# Why is there more than one HWadder while running command ifconfig

Tags: ifconfig

[image]I performed the ifconfig command in Linux to find out my mac address. But as there are multiple HWadder in the output I can't find out my MAC address. I also want to know, why do they show multiple MAC addresses while only one mac address is possible. I am connected with wifi instead of Lan, is it a reason for this?? The screenshot is given below:

Answer (score 2):

> But as there are multiple HWadder in the output I can't find out my MAC address.

You have one MAC address for your LAN interface (`eno1`) and one for your WLAN interface (`wlo1`), that's correct and how it should be. Each network interface has its own MAC address.

> while only one mac address is possible.

Who says "only one MAC address is possible per computer"?

> I am connected with wifi

Then the MAC address you are currently using is your WLAN MAC address. Obviously.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have heard that mac address is used to identify a device uniquely. that's why I thought so.

Comment: People attempted years ago (when the MAC address was still hardcoded in EEPROMs) to use MAC information together with other information to identify a system uniquely, but for most modern hardware, you can change the MAC anyway, so that's not particularly working well... and even back then, more than one MAC was possible (just put in multiple network cards). No idea what those half-baked protection schemes did in that case...